# Separate/reposition/translate shapes in image with pillow in python

Tags: python, algorithm, image-manipulation, python-imaging-library

I need to separate or translate or replace pixels in an image with python so as to all the shapes to share the same distance between each other and the limits of the canvas.

background is white, shapes are black.

IMPORTANT: Images are dynamic, all images have bars at different positions, that means i need to detect where a bar starts and where a bar ends to draw the final image!

This is an example INPUT image

[image]

This is an example OUTPUT image

[image]

I did this by hand, i don't know if all bars are separated by the same distance, it's just an example.

The resulting canvas size can change too but ideally i would like all canvas to have the same width and height after the bars have been respositioned.

All pixels in the images are BLACK or WHITE, that should make it much easier.

What i've tried so far kind of detects the shapes but some shapes are not detected correctly when they are too close of each other:

```
saut = 1
start_ab = 0
end_ab = 0
start_or = im2.size[1] - 1
end_or = 0
size = 0

shapes = []

for y in range(0, im2.size[0], saut):  # slice across
    for x in range(0, im2.size[1], 1):  # slice down
        pix = im2.getpixel((y, x))
        if pix != 255:
            start_or = min(start_or, x)
            end_or = max(end_or, x)
            inshape = True

    if foundshape == False and inshape == True:
        foundshape = True
        start_ab = y

    if foundshape == True and inshape == False:
        foundshape = False
        end_ab = y
        size = max(size, end_ab)
        shapes.append((start_ab, end_ab, start_or, end_or))
        start_or = im2.size[1] - 1
        end_or = 0
    inshape = False

print shapes
# example shapes output NOT FROM THE EXAMPLE IMAGES PROVIDED but from other shapes [(54, 171, 72, 233), (216, 324, 108, 251), (342, 486, 0, 215), (513, 765, 18, 260), (792, 918, 90, 242)]
```

And still have to draw the new image, i don't know how to do that, also some images have shapes with "holes" in them, so that makes the "redraw" a little bit more complicated.

Comment: Can you edit your code to include the imports you are making, so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @S4M no, i don't need you to reproduce my problem, if you answer the question thats more than enough, also, if you need the images, work with the ones provided in the eample

Comment: From reading your code, it seems that your shape are defined by `(start_ab, end_ab, start_or, end_or)`, if I understand well, that characterizes the coordinates of a rectangle, so I think you have to get the holes as well. I suggest scanning all the coordinates between the points `(start_ab, start_or)` and (end_ab,end_or)` and list the ones that are empty, so your shapes will be characterized by `(start_ab, end_ab, start_or, end_or,empty_points)`, where `empty_points` will be a list of points.

Comment: Yes i know S4M, thanks for pointing it out, the thing is, that has nothing to do with the problem here, can you answer the question?

Comment: Is this the question: "And still have to draw the new image, i don't know how to do that, also some images have shapes with "holes" in them, so that makes the "redraw" a little bit more complicated." ? In that case, you just need to store the shapes as I suggested and then go through the data you have, shift the abscissa accordingly and fill the pixels when they are not empty. I can write you some pseudo code for that - it will not work because I don't know the libraries you are using but you should be able to adjust it.

Comment: Libraries i'm using are `PIL hashlib time os math`, anyways the question says in the title "PIL/Python"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And still have to draw the new image, i don't know how to do that, also some images have shapes with "holes" in them, so that makes the "redraw" a little bit more complicated.

Once you've established the bounds of a rectangle, you could use the Image.crop() function to extract a rectangle from the image (including those holes) and Image.paste() to paste them in the right position. The tutorial contains an example:

http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html#cutting-pasting-and-merging-images

Comment: Nice Michiel, gonna try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Code to calculate the distance between each shape. It assumes that the shapes have all the same width:

```
def calcDistanceBetweenShapes(nShapes, shapeWidth, totalWidth):
    totalBlank = totalWidth-nShapes*shapeWidth
    return totalBlank/nShapes
```

Code to shift a shape's abscissa (assumes a shape is stored as `(start_ab, end_ab, start_or, end_or,empty_points)`):

```
def setNewAbscissa(shape, new_start_ab):
    start_ab, end_ab = shape[0], shape[1]
    shift = new_start_ab - start_ab
    new_end_ab = end_ab + shift
    new_empty_points = map(lambda pt: (pt[0]+shift,pt[1]),empty_points)
    return (new_start_ab, new_end_ab,start_or, end_or, new_empty_points)
```

Now let's call `d` the distance between shapes. The first shape will not be moved, so its coordinates stay the same. The second shape will have its `start_ab` that will be `previous_end_ab+d` where `previous_end_ab` is the `end_ab` of the first shape, etc. This gives an algorithm to calculate the coordinates of all the shapes.

```
def get_new_shapes(shapes, totalWidth):
    shift = calcDistanceBetweenShapes(len(shapes), shapes[0][1] - shape[0][0], totalWidth)
    res = [shapes[0]]
    previous_shape = shapes[0]
    for shape in shape[1:]:
         new_start_ab = previous_shape[1] + shift
         new_shape =  setNewAbscissa(previous_shape,new_start_ab)
         res.append(new_shape)
         previous_shape = new_shape
```